# the button doesn't postback which opened by PopupCenter

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I used the Popupcenter function which is from  [neofnd/popupCenter](https://gist.github.com/neofnd/4151610cb139d6896099) to open the aspx page. The aspx page is opened but buttons in the aspx page doesn't fire, no postback. Does someone tell me how to solve it. Thanks in advance.

There is the code from github

```
function PopupCenter(url, title, w, h) {  
// Fixes dual-screen position                         Most browsers      Firefox  
var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;  
var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;  

width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;  
height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;  

var left = ((width / 2) - (w / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;  
var top = ((height / 2) - (h / 2)) + dualScreenTop;  
var newWindow = window.open(url, title, 'scrollbars=yes, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);  

// Puts focus on the newWindow  
if (window.focus) {  
    newWindow.focus();  

}
```

}

There is my button to open call this function.

Comment: Can you post the code that calls the PopupCenter function?

Comment: Are you looking to have the popup window postback to the parent window? You should post the basic HTML content of the form that goes in the popup.

Comment: @MichaelvE  I called it insid javascript function. The is my code:  PopupCenter(url, window,height,width);